# Automatically Highlighted Pdf Code Export [Org-Mode]

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I want my Org Mode Latex Pdf Export to look like [Code Styles and Colours](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_listing)

---

Colour definitions for the **xcolor** package have been added to

```
org-format-latex-header
```

It looks like that now:

```
 (setq org-format-latex-header 
       '("\\documentclass{article}
 \\usepackage[usenames]{color}
 [PACKAGES]
 [DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
 \\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
 \\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
 \\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
 \\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

 \\pagestyle{empty}             % do not remove
 % The settings below are copied from fullpage.sty
 \\setlength{\\textwidth}{\\paperwidth}
 \\addtolength{\\textwidth}{-3cm}
 \\setlength{\\oddsidemargin}{1.5cm}
 \\addtolength{\\oddsidemargin}{-2.54cm}
 \\setlength{\\evensidemargin}{\\oddsidemargin}
 \\setlength{\\textheight}{\\paperheight}
 \\addtolength{\\textheight}{-\\headheight}
 \\addtolength{\\textheight}{-\\headsep}
 \\addtolength{\\textheight}{-\\footskip}
 \\addtolength{\\textheight}{-3cm}
 \\setlength{\\topmargin}{1.5cm}
 \\addtolength{\\topmargin}{-2.54cm}"
         )
       )
```

---

**mystyle** settings

```
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{...}
```

have been added to

```
org-latex-listings-options
```

It looks like that now:

```
     (setq org-latex-listings-options
       '(("backgroundcolor" "\\color{backcolour}")
         ("commentstyle" "\\color{codegreen}")
         ("keywordstyle" "\\color{magenta}")
         ("numberstyle" "\\tiny\\color{codegray}")
         ("stringstyle" "\\color{codepurple}")
         ("basicstyle" "\\ttfamily\\footnotesize")
         ("breakatwhitespace" "false")
         ("breaklines" "true")
         ("captionpos" "b")
         ("keepspaces" "true")
         ("numbers" "left")
         ("numbersep" "5pt")
         ("showspaces" "false")
         ("showstringspaces" "false")
         ("showtabs" "false")
         ("tabsize" "2")
         )
       )
```

---

If I now use the export dispatcher with **C-c C-e l L**, and analyze the buffer nothing has changed.

---

**1. Am I adjusting the settings/variables incorrectly?**

**2. Is there a better org mode way to get an automatically generated .pdf with code style highlighting?**

---

> **Edit 1:**
>
> the *org-latex-listings-options* is inserted above every
>
> ```
> \begin{lstlisting}
> ...
> \end{lstlisting}
> ```
>
> and not once above the *\begin{document}*
>
> **3. How can I optimize that**

---

> **Edit 2:** Here some example Files (Naming should clarify the purpose)
>   Don´t know how to attach files in StackExchange
>
> [File Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14XbR5eGKlC5wePG_4F0ohxJ4CZGDgRhY?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please provide a mininal org file on which one can see the problem?

Comment: I edited the post with a gdrive link to some example files.